# Source for eulogy of lost bookcases

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, talmud-bavli, agada-stories-legends, story-identification

I recall learning a gemarah (Bavli) where a certain scholar passed away and when another scholar was asked to eulogize him he responded with something akin to, "What should I say? We lost our bookcases?"

Where can this gemarah be found?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Megillah 28b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=28b&format=pdf) ([English](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Megilah.pdf))

> ההוא דהוי תני הלכתא סיפרא וסיפרי ותוספתא ושכיב אתו ואמרו ליה לרב נחמן ליספדיה מר אמר היכי נספדיה הי צנא דמלי סיפרי דחסר
>
> there was a certain man who used to
> repeat halachoth, Sifra and Sifre and Tosefta, and when he died they came and said to R. Nahman,
> Sir, will you deliver a funeral oration for him, and he said, How are we to deliver over him an
> address: Alas! A bag full of books has been lost!

Comment: Congratulations on your 200th bronze star!

Comment: @Ypnypn Thanks muchly. If all goes well I should have exactly 100 silver ones by the end of the night.

Comment: @Ypnypn Check it out http://i.stack.imgur.com/i5vsJ.png